# viewpager2 get adapter of current fragment cause NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I use mAdapter.getTotalPriceInRecyclerView() to get total price in current selected page in viewpage2+Tablayout.

but it will cause NullPointerException because the mAdapter created in **onCreateView** method.

How could I make sure mAdapter has been initialed?

I use viewpage2 to create new Fragment (TheFragmentClass.newInstance()) rather than beginTransaction().commit

```
private boolean createFragment(int tabLimited) {
    if (mVp2Adapter.getItemCount() >= tabLimited) {
        return false;
    }
    String tabText = getTimeOfHMS();
    SettlementProductItemFragment fragment = SettlementProductItemFragment.newInstance(); // new intance
    mVp2Adapter.addFragment(tabText, fragment); // add to viewpage2's adapter
    mTabSettlementProduct.selectTab(mTabSettlementProduct.getTabAt(
            mVp2Adapter.getItemCount() - 1));
    return true;
}

public void addFragment(String title, Fragment fragment) {
    if (mFragmentTitles.contains(title)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "addFragment failed: mFragmentTitles.contains(" + title + ")");
        return;
    }
    mFragments.put(title, fragment);
    mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    updateHashMap();
    notifyItemInserted(mFragmentTitles.size() - 1);
}
```

Here's my SettlementProductItemFragment class.

```
public class SettlementProductItemFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRvProductInFragment;

public SettlementProductItemFragment() {
}


public static SettlementProductItemFragment newInstance() {
    SettlementProductItemFragment fragment = new SettlementProductItemFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

private SettlementProductItemRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

public double getTotalPriceInFragment() {
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("mAdapter(SettlementProductItemRecyclerViewAdapter) CAN NOT BE NULL");
    }
    return mAdapter.getTotalPriceInRecyclerView();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settlement_product_item_list, container, false);
    Log.e("getTotalPriceInFragment", "onCreateView: " + view.getClass().toString());
    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        mAdapter = new SettlementProductItemRecyclerViewAdapter(context, getProducts());
        mRvProductInFragment = (RecyclerView) view;
        mRvProductInFragment.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        mRvProductInFragment.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    return view;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use ViewPager2 you have `setOffscreenPageLimit` method (offscreenPageLimit property in Kotlin) it will retain **(and precreate also)** your fragment when you initilize your ViewPager2.

The problem that i see in your code is that you modify items in ViewPager adapter. It isn't default snippet for using viewPager2 + tabs, so make sure you do it well, check for [ViewPager2 samples by Google](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2)

Alternatively, you can create property in your `SettlementProductItemFragment` e.g `isInitialized` and observe it in your host fragment. In that way i suppose you have to use Architecture Components like [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) + [Livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)